# I want to add another switch and fixture from a switch

Tags: electrical, switch

I have power coming through a light to the switch with 12/3 wire. at the switch location I want to add another switch  to another fixture. How do I wire it?

Comment: Need more information. Is it a 3 way switch? Or single pole but with both black and red hot? Actually a picture would answer all those questions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is a single pole. And I want to add separate single pole. I ran power 12/2 to the ceiling fixture then down to switch with 12/3. In that same switch box I want to a another switch which will go to an outside light fixture. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh then you just need to pigtail line wire to the new switch. Easy.

Comment: great thank you!!